# Padding both ends of n-grams

Tags: python, nltk, padding, n-gram

I am trying to write a function to generate n-grams for each phrase in my dataset. I have included the first phrase as an example.

I am padding each phrase with `<s>` and `</s>` using `pad_both_ends` from `NLTK`. I can't figure out why it's creating an extra two sets of padding at the start and end of the phrase. Is there a way I can remove it? `ans_n` must be 4 in this case. Here is my code:

```
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import pad_both_ends
from nltk import bigrams

my_phrases[0] = [‘It’, ‘is’, ‘my’, ‘favorite’, ‘place’, ‘ever’, ‘.’]

def my_ngrams(n, phrases):

    all_ngrams = []
    
    for i in range(len(phrases)):
        grams = list(bigrams(pad_both_ends(phrases[i], n)))
        all_ngrams.append(grams)

return all_ngrams

ans_n = 4
ans_ngrams = my_ngrams(ans_n, my_phrases)
ans_ngrams

[('<s>', '<s>'),
 ('<s>', '<s>'),
 ('<s>', ‘It’),
 (’It’, ‘is),
 (‘is’, ‘my’),
 (‘my’, ‘favorite’),
 (‘favorite’, ‘place’),
 (‘place’, ‘ever’),
 (‘ever’, ‘.’),
 (‘.’, '</s>'),
 ('</s>', '</s>'),
 ('</s>', '</s>')]
```

Desired output:

```
[('<s>', 'It'),
 ('It', 'is'),
 ('is', 'my'),
 ('my', 'favorite'),
 ('favorite', 'place'),
 ('place', 'ever'),
 ('ever', '.'),
 (',', '</s>')]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the NTLK documentation, `pad_both_ends` calls the function [`pad_sequence`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.util.html?highlight=pad_sequence#nltk.util.pad_sequence), which, given `n=4`, as specified in your code, will output the sequence

```py
['<s>', '<s>', '<s>', 'It', 'is', 'my', 'favorite', 'place', 'ever', '.', '</s>', '</s>', '</s>']
```

with `n-1` padding symbols at both ends.
Then, the `bigrams` function calls the [`ngrams`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#ngrams) function, which does output the sequence of bigrams, without any filtering.
To get the desired output, you need to use `n=2` in `pad_both_ends`, as is intended by the library, or filter the output bigrams you get, with for instance a `set` instead of a `list` to get rid of the doubles, and then manually remove the `['<s>', '<s>']` and `['</s>', '</s>']`.

But I'm not sure what you mean by

> `ans_n` must be 4 in this case